# FPDF Multiply Table PHP PDO

Tags: php, html, fpdf

I need to print the curriculum data's in PDF file. On the Front-End got no problem.

[image]

But applying the same code on FPDF is kinda hard for me. I need to display the curriculum data's like on my front-end. I made this so far.

[image]

And here is the whole code for that script.

```
<?php
include "../../include/student_session.php";
$user_id = $_SESSION['student'];
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT *, h.campus as 'h.campus', k.batch as 'k.batch', j.id as 'j.id', a.department_id as 'dept' FROM student_info a
                                    INNER JOIN section b ON b.id = a.section_id
                                    INNER JOIN course c ON c.id = a.course_id
                                    INNER JOIN year_tbl d ON d.id = a.year_id
                                    INNER JOIN batch_tbl e ON e.id = a.batch_id
                                    INNER JOIN department f ON f.id = a.department_id
                                    INNER JOIN scholarship g ON g.id = a.scholarship_id
                                    INNER JOIN campus h ON h.id = a.campus
                                    INNER JOIN school_year i ON i.id = a.sy_id
                                    INNER JOIN curriculum j ON j.department_id = a.department_id AND j.course_id = a.course_id
                                    INNER JOIN batch_tbl k ON k.id = j.batch_id
                                    WHERE a.id=:id");
$stmt->execute(array(":id"=>$user_id));
$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF {
    function Header() {
        // Logo

        $this->Image('../../login-folder/assets/img/logo_ac_long.png',68,10,80);

    }
    function Footer() {
        // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'R');
        //$this->Line(20, 45, 210-20, 45); // 20mm from each edge
        $this->GetY(15); 
        $x=$this->GetY(15); 
        //$this->Line(160,250,296-100,250); 

        $this->Line(10,285,200,285); 
        $this->Ln(); 
        $fech = time(); 
        $fecha = date( "m/d/y" ,$fech); 
        $this->Text(10,288,$fecha);
    }
}


$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);

$pdf->Ln(30);
$pdf->Cell(10);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','', 8);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Student Number: '.$userRow['student_no']);
$pdf->Cell(70);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Section Block : '.$userRow['section_code']);

$pdf->Ln(6);
$pdf->Cell(10);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Reference No  : ----------');
$pdf->Cell(70);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'School Year   : '.$userRow['school_year']);

$pdf->Ln(6);
$pdf->Cell(10);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Name          : '.$userRow['student_name']);
$pdf->Cell(70);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Semester      : '.$userRow['semester']);

$pdf->Ln(6);
$pdf->Cell(10);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Course          : '.$userRow['course_code']);
$pdf->Cell(70);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Year            : '.$userRow['year']);

$pdf->Ln(6);
$pdf->Cell(10);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Curriculum    : Ver.'.$userRow['j.id'].', '.$userRow['k.batch']);
$pdf->Cell(70);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Status        : Currently Enrolled');

$pdf->Ln(6);
$pdf->Cell(10);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Campus        : '.$userRow['campus']);
$pdf->Cell(70);
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Scholarship   : '.$userRow['scholarship_type']);
$stmt5 = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT *,a.id as 'a.id', b.year_id as 'b.year_id' FROM year_tbl a INNER JOIN subjects b ON b.year_id = a.id AND department_id = :dept group by a.id order by a.id asc; ");
$stmt5->bindparam(":dept", $userRow['dept']);
$stmt5->execute();
$userRow5=$stmt5->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($stmt5->rowCount() > 0) {
    foreach ($userRow5 as $key) {
            $pdf->Ln(10);
            $pdf->Cell(10);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
            $pdf->Cell(30,5,$key['year']. ' - ' .$key['semester']);

            //set initial y axis position per page
            $y_axis_initial = 86;
            //Set Row Height
            $row_height = 6;

            //print column titles for the actual page
            $pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);

            $pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
            $pdf->SetX(12);


            $pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'Subject Code', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
            $pdf->Cell(10, 6, 'Units', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
            $pdf->Cell(12, 6, 'Prelims', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
            $pdf->Cell(14, 6, 'Remarks', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
            $pdf->Cell(12, 6, 'Midterm', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
            $pdf->Cell(14, 6, 'Remarks', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
            $pdf->Cell(12, 6, 'Finals', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
            $pdf->Cell(14, 6, 'Remarks', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
            $pdf->Cell(12, 6, 'Average', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
            $pdf->Cell(14, 6, 'Equivalent', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
            $pdf->Cell(40, 6, 'Instructor', 1, 0, 'C', 1);

            $y_axis = $y_axis_initial  + $row_height;
            //initialize counter
            $i = 0;

            //Set maximum rows per page
            $max = 25;

            $stmt2 = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT *, d.id as 'b.section_id', c.id as 'b.subject_id', c.subject_code as 'c.subject_code', a.year_id as 'yid', a.batch_id as 'bid', (lec_units + lab_units) as 'total'  FROM student_info a
                                    INNER JOIN curriculum b ON b.department_id = a.department_id AND b.batch_id = a.batch_id AND b.course_id = a.course_id
                                    INNER JOIN curriculum_subjects f ON f.curriculum_id = b.id
                                    INNER JOIN subjects c ON c.id = f.subject_id AND c.year_id = :yid
                                    INNER JOIN section d ON d.id = a.section_id
                                    INNER JOIN batch_tbl e ON e.id = a.batch_id

                                    WHERE a.student_no = :value");
            $stmt2->bindparam(":value", $userRow['student_no']);
            $stmt2->bindparam(":yid", $key['a.id']);
            $stmt2->execute();
            $userRow2=$stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if ($stmt2->rowCount() > 0) {
                foreach ($userRow2 as $key2) {

                    if ($i == $max) {
                        $pdf->AddPage();

                        //print column titles for the current page
                        $pdf->SetY($y_axis_initial);
                        $pdf->SetX(33);

                        //$pdf->Cell(30, 6, 'Resident', 1, 0, 'L', 1);

                        $pdf->Cell($pdf->GetStringWidth('Subject Code')+3, 6, 'Subject Code', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
                        $pdf->Cell($pdf->GetStringWidth('Units')+3, 6, 'Units', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
                        $pdf->Cell($pdf->GetStringWidth('Prelims')+3, 6, 'Prelims', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
                        $pdf->Cell($pdf->GetStringWidth('Remarks')+3, 6, 'Remarks', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
                        $pdf->Cell($pdf->GetStringWidth('Midterm')+3, 6, 'Midterm', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
                        $pdf->Cell($pdf->GetStringWidth('Remarks')+3, 6, 'Remarks', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
                        $pdf->Cell($pdf->GetStringWidth('Finals')+3, 6, 'Finals', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
                        $pdf->Cell($pdf->GetStringWidth('Remarks')+3, 6, 'Remarks', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
                        $pdf->Cell($pdf->GetStringWidth('Average')+3, 6, 'Average', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
                        $pdf->Cell($pdf->GetStringWidth('Equivalent')+3, 6, 'Equivalent', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
                        $pdf->Cell($pdf->GetStringWidth('Instructor')+3, 6, 'Instructor', 1, 0, 'L', 1);
                        //Go to next row
                        $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

                        //Set $i variable to 0 (first row)
                        $i = 0;
                    }
                    $semester = $key2['subject_code'];
                    $pdf->SetY($y_axis);
                    $pdf->SetX(12);
                    $pdf->Cell(30, 6, $semester, 1, 0, 'C', 1);
                    $pdf->Cell(10, 6, '', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
                    $pdf->Cell(12, 6, '', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
                    $pdf->Cell(14, 6, '', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
                    $pdf->Cell(12, 6, '', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
                    $pdf->Cell(14, 6, '', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
                    $pdf->Cell(12, 6, '', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
                    $pdf->Cell(14, 6, '', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
                    $pdf->Cell(12, 6, '', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
                    $pdf->Cell(14, 6, '', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
                    $pdf->Cell(40, 6, '', 1, 0, 'C', 1);
                    //Go to next row
                    $y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
                    $i = $i + 1;
                }
                $pdf->Output();
            }

    }
//    $pdf->Ln(10);
//    $pdf->Cell(10);
//    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','b', 8);
//    $pdf->Cell(30,5,'NOTE: THIS IS NOT VALID WHEN THERE IS NO SIGNATURE OF REGISTAR OFFICE.');

}
?>
```

**What mistake did I do here? What I'm missing? I need help to achieve the front-end output like that.**

Comment: What's wrong with the output? What aspect of the front-end are you trying to replicate? There are too many differences for someone to just write it for you. You might consider upwork if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I already fix it :) thanks